# New Exchange SSL certificate now Windows XP Outlook clients won't connect

Tags: ssl, windows-xp, ssl-certificate, outlook, exchange-2013

I renewed our SSL certificate for Exchange but now Outlook won't connect on any Windows XP machines. It asks for the username and password and even when the correct credentials are entered it just asks for them again over and over as if they are incorrect. Is there something that I missed when renewing our Exchange SSL certificate?

Comment: You missed decommissioning the ancient XP boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Exchange Certificate common name - it must match the exchange server name. 
Even if the Exchange server name is listed in the SAN (subject alternative names) windows XP will prompt for credentials. So you can make sure that when you create the certificate that the Exchange name is the common name or run the following command:
**Set-OutlookProvider EXPR -CertPrincipalName:”msstd:mail.company.com”** (mail.company.com is the name of your certificate)

For the Set-OutlookProvider command EXCH is for internal OWA clients and EXPR is for external clients.